# Blueprism - Get all items - Field names are duplicated

Tags: listview, blueprism

I'm trying to import a list from an windows application, but unfortunately, there are 2 fields with the same name.

The element type is "List view", and I tried using a "reader" action, and "get all items", but the error "Invalid collection data returned from action - are field names duplicated?" persists.

I understand that it's not possible to have a collection with equal fields, but I tried to define the collection fields before importing, but it gives the same error.

Is there any possible solution to solve this? There's no way I can change the fields in the application, and the field can't be identified without including the headers.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to spy an individual field and read the fields one-by-one into your named collection?

Comment: I can identify the whole fields region, but not an individual field. Is there a way to tell blueprism to import the list, but to ignore the headers? For example, to consider the fields as a normal collection row, plus the remaining rows.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you have a real conundrum on your hand. The issue is that when you are reading a list of values into a collection the blank collection has a restriction that you must have unique identifiers on each column for (that you identified in your question). I suggest some potential work-arounds because this is a hard restriction in Blueprism that you will find difficult to overcome when working with multiple columns with the same name.

**First (possibly easiest):** collecting data from different points in the system. It sounds like you are viewing data and collating it into Blueprism. It might be worth talking to an expert in the company that uses this tool are there any other screens where you may grab this data, then you might be able to grab the same data from a different location and collate it into one collection inside Blueprism.

**Second (more technical):** using a different spy mode like AA. AA has the ability to read tables as well as win32 options however AA has some really cool/strict criteria where you can explore the ability to read only one column of data then parse the columns in one at a time into an internal collection inside Blueprism.

**Third (alternate spying):** Check your application with all the spy modes and see can you spy the individual fields one by one. Then if you can spy the cells you can spy the first row then feed them dynamic parameters to loop through the whole table and build a collection internally.

**Fourth (less desired):** Tesseract engine OCR reading. You could try read the text on the screen with the OCR engine provided with Blueprism. Its not easy quite fiddly but if the system is stable and you get it working it will work just fine for a long time.

**Fifth (dependancies):** is it possible you can export the table view into an excel or CSV or notepad locally then extract that into Blueprism using MS Excel VBO?

**Sixth (lastly):** can you click the table, Ctrl A and Ctrl C it to get the data into the clipboard to pull it out form there then do some string manipulation son it to get the data back into collection somehow. warning: fragile solution dont encourage but could be a way of doing it.

Very last option, you could always ask the application owner can they put a change in to request the change of name for that column and see if they'd do it but you shouldn't have to.

Hope that helps!